# Pandas read_csv: Multiple file loads using individual variables - date conversion function gets Unbound error

Tags: python, pandas

**The questions:**

Why is the date conversion function throwing the error on empty values?
How can I force convert an object into a datetime value to subsequently insert into a database table?

The following is a bit long-winded. Sorry, I try to capture only the essential parts as I have not found any working answer so far on SO for this combination of coding.

**Background**

Using variables (plus including lists and dicts) my import function can treat different file imports always the same.
The code snippet for the import is as follows:

```
    for dataset in pd.read_csv( file_in, chunksize = 50000, sep = col_sep, encoding = encoded, header = row_head,
      names = col_names, usecols = col_names, parse_dates = col_dates, converters = col_cv_map):
    ...
```

One example for the variables is like:

```
        col_names       = [ 'code_purchase_order', 'code_container', 'type_container', 'name_vessel', 'code_carrier_bill', 'date_planned_receipt',
                           'date_estimate_depart', 'date_estimate_arrival', 'date_nolo_container', 'name_nolo_comment', 'date_pan_diff_eta', 
                           'date_kn_diff_eta', 'name_port_load', 'date_adod', 'code_warehouse', 'name_ship_to', 'name_carrier', 
                           'flag_hannover_warehouse', 'flag_extra_work_plan'
                        ]
        col_dates       = [ 'date_planned_receipt', 'date_estimate_depart', 'date_estimate_arrival', 'date_nolo_container', 
                           'date_pan_diff_eta', 'date_kn_diff_eta', 'date_adod'
                          ]
        col_cv_map      = { 'type_container':cv_quote, 'date_planned_receipt':cv_forcedate, 'date_estimate_depart':cv_forcedate,
                           'date_estimate_arrival':cv_forcedate, 'date_nolo_container':cv_forcedate, 'date_pan_diff_eta':cv_forcedate,
                           'date_kn_diff_eta':cv_forcedate, 'date_adod':cv_forcedate
                          }
        col_sep         = ';'
```

The data frame is then written to a database table using pandas to_sql method.
This works well except where no date values exist in columns. In these cases I get back an object from the date parsing instead of a date.

The function for the numeric conversion works fine, the function to force a date out of an object results in error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out_dt' referenced before assignment
```

And I can see that the function goes into the except branch as this outputs:
Error converting to date: <>
Meaning the empty value can not be converted to a date result.

**Coding**

For comparison the cv_number function works fine, the cv_forcedate throws an exception.

```
def cv_number(in_obj):
    """Convert incoming string into number"""
    try:
        out_num = float( in_obj.replace(',', '.') )
    except ValueError:
        out_num = ny.nan
    except:
        print(f'Error converting to number: <{in_obj}> ')
    return out_num

def cv_forcedate(in_obj):
    """Forces object to datetime"""
    try:
        # try first format yyyy/mm/dd
        dt_fmt = '%Y/%m/%d'
        out_dt = in_obj.apply(lambda _: datetime.strptime(_, dt_fmt)) #datetime.strptime(in_obj, dt_fmt)
    except ValueError:
        out_dt = ny.nat
    except:
        print(f'Error converting to date: <{in_obj}>')
    return out_dt
```

When I compare the execution both seem to work the same way:

```
import dis    
dis.dis(cv_number)
108           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            20 (to 22)
109           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (float)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (in_obj)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (replace)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (',')
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('.')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (out_num)
             18 POP_BLOCK
             20 JUMP_FORWARD            52 (to 74)
110     >>   22 DUP_TOP
             24 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (ValueError)
             26 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       46
             30 POP_TOP
             32 POP_TOP
             34 POP_TOP
111          36 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (ny)
             38 LOAD_ATTR                4 (nan)
             40 STORE_FAST               1 (out_num)
             42 POP_EXCEPT
             44 JUMP_FORWARD            28 (to 74)
112     >>   46 POP_TOP
             48 POP_TOP
             50 POP_TOP
113          52 LOAD_GLOBAL              5 (print)
             54 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Error converting to number: <')
             56 LOAD_FAST                0 (in_obj)
             58 FORMAT_VALUE             0
             60 LOAD_CONST               4 ('> ')
             62 BUILD_STRING             3
             64 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             66 POP_TOP
             68 POP_EXCEPT
             70 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 74)
             72 END_FINALLY
114     >>   74 LOAD_FAST                1 (out_num)
             76 RETURN_VALUE

import dis
dis.dis(cv_forcedate)
118           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            26 (to 28)
120           2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%Y/%m/%d')
              4 STORE_DEREF              0 (dt_fmt)
121           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (in_obj)
              8 LOAD_ATTR                0 (apply)
             10 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (dt_fmt)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <lambda> at 0x7f8b2d4878a0, file "<ipython-input-16-91bdd92a24b3>", line 121>)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 ('cv_forcedate.<locals>.<lambda>')
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (out_dt)
             24 POP_BLOCK
             26 JUMP_FORWARD            52 (to 80)
122     >>   28 DUP_TOP
             30 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (ValueError)
             32 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             34 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       52
             36 POP_TOP
             38 POP_TOP
             40 POP_TOP
123          42 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (ny)
             44 LOAD_ATTR                3 (nat)
             46 STORE_FAST               1 (out_dt)
             48 POP_EXCEPT
             50 JUMP_FORWARD            28 (to 80)
124     >>   52 POP_TOP
             54 POP_TOP
             56 POP_TOP
125          58 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (print)
             60 LOAD_CONST               4 ('Error converting to date: <')
             62 LOAD_FAST                0 (in_obj)
             64 FORMAT_VALUE             0
             66 LOAD_CONST               5 ('>')
             68 BUILD_STRING             3
             70 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             72 POP_TOP
             74 POP_EXCEPT
             76 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 80)
             78 END_FINALLY
126     >>   80 LOAD_FAST                1 (out_dt)
             82 RETURN_VALUE
```

In particular if possible I try to determine what I am doing wrong as all the demo and example coding I found has always used well formed test cases which just do not match the real life data I am working with.